# Using multiple sets of credentials with GCP API calls

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform

I have a long running process that *subscribes* to Pub/Sub topic A and *publishes* to Pub/Sub topic B. The process uses two distinct sets of credentials: one that allows it to subscribe to A and one to publish to B. These credentials are JSON files with credentials to two different service acccounts.

The process flow looks something like this:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# create publisher
project_id  = "my-project-id"
subscr_id_A = "subscribe-A"
topic_id_B  = "topic-B"

# create subscriber
subscriber        = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscr_id_A)

# create publisher
publisher_options = pubsub_v1.types.PublisherOptions(enable_message_ordering=True)
publisher         = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(publisher_options=publisher_options)
topic_path        = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id_B)

while (True):
    response = subscriber.pull(subscription_path)
    # ... other things ...
  
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
```

In simpler contexts I usually set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path of my service account credentials file. As already noted I have *two* credentials file.

I am looking for Google documentation (or some tests that someone has carried out) that answers this question:
Do I need to set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` before *every* pull and publish? Or is it sufficient to set it only before the SubscriberClient and PublisherClient create?

Comment: In your case do not use the environment variable, which is almost always a bad idea. You have at least three options. 1) Create each client specifying the service account **once**. My guess is that you are creating the client over and over. 2) Use one service account that has permission to both topics. 3) Do not use a service account at all and use the attached service account if your code is running in the cloud. Summary: You do not include enough details on the running environment or the code which is required for a good answer.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify the code structure.

Comment: Your question: ***Do I need to set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS before every pull and publish?***. No, credentials are resolved when you create the client. **pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()**. Changing the environment variable after that line of code will have no effect on that client instance. The best way to know the answer is to look at the source code, which Google publishes. https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/main/google/pubsub_v1/services/subscriber/client.py

Comment: Since you are using more than one service account, declare the service account when creating the client. `pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient.from_service_account_file(...)`.

Comment: I wonder why there is a `from_service_account_file` method for `SubscriberClient` but not for `PublisherClient`...

Comment: PublisherClient supports `from_service_account_File` as well. https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/google.cloud.pubsub_v1.publisher.client.Client#google_cloud_pubsub_v1_publisher_client_Client_from_service_account_file